# Counting strings row wise in Crystal report

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have Crystal Report which has similar scenario as below. I want to count number of “A”,”P” , “W” occurs in each row.

If any row does not contain above then it should return 0 (zero). If the row contains above  then I should count them.

Any ideas please, how to count the numbers of “A”,”P”,”W” in each row through crystal report

[image: report format]?

Comment: Can you give the values you'd expect for all 5 rows? Also is this in a cross-tab?

Comment: I have already attached a sample Image having expected value. second this is not a cross tab report.

Comment: @bendataclea : in attached image expected value are in red color..

Comment: Ah ok I see, are the `1, 2, 3 & 4` columns fields in your database? Will you only ever have these four fields?

Comment: No, field will be generate dynamic, these field can be max 31. actually i am using linq for PIVOT the employee attendance record, finally i am getting above output so i want summery at last of crystal report.

Comment: You can use temp table in query and then display record in Report.Because here is not possible in crystal report.

Comment: How are you handling dynamic columns in Crustal if not through a cross tab report? Are you adding fields to the report at runtime in code?

Comment: Yes, I am using parameter field for generating report at runtime. having any idea?

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to generate the report? You will need to add formulas to the report using code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a lenghty solution but that will work.

Below soltion should be used taking into consideration:
1. Number of fields are constant in report that is fields are not dynamic.
2. A,P, W are hard coded values and should be used in report asit is that is these shouldn't have dynamic nature.

Below is the code:
1. Create formulas for all fileds in below code I named those as a, a1,a1.
2. Now create a another formula for "A" and implement below code

```
EvaluateAfter({@a});
EvaluateAfter({@a 2});
EvaluateAfter({@a 3});


    Local StringVar a;
    Local StringVar a1;
    Local StringVar a2;
    Local NumberVar i;
    Local NumberVar j;
    Local StringVar array x;
    a:={@a};
    a1:={@a 2};
    a2:={@a 3};
    x:=[a,a1,a2];
    j:=0;
    for i:=1 to Count(x) do
    (
    if x[i]="A"
    Then j:=j+1;
    );
    j
```

Take the all values inside varialbes and loop for every record to get count.

Place the formulas in detail section, You will get result.

Let me know incase any issue.